# The function for removing loop in a linked list gives runtime error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Remove loop in Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/remove-loop-in-linked-list/1)
:

> Given a linked list of `N` nodes such that it may contain a loop.
>
> A loop here means that the last node of the link list is connected to the node at position `X` (1-based index). If the link list does not have any loop, `X=0`.
>
> Remove the loop from the linked list, if it is present, i.e. unlink the last node which is forming the loop.

My attempt gives a runtime error for some of the test cases:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at Solution.removeLoop(GFG.java:123)
>    at GFG.main(GFG.java:86)
> ```

```
public static void removeLoop(Node head){
    // remove the loop without losing any nodes
    Node slow=head;
    Node fast=head;
    Node node=head;
    Node pre=null;
    while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
        slow=slow.next;
        fast=fast.next.next;
        if(slow==fast){
            while(node!=slow){
                pre=slow;
                node=node.next;
                slow=slow.next;
            }
            pre.next=null;  // line 123
        }
    }
}
```

I marked the line that is mentioned in the error message. Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: What's the error message exactly?

Comment: I might be misreading this...  It seems to me node==slow in the 2nd loop will almost never happen, as they both move at the same speed.  Imagine Nascar, and slow is on the main loop while node is in the pit.  Both cars set off at the same speed.  Odds of them meeting right out of the pit are very small (and get smaller the larger the track, i.e. loop).  But if it doesn't happen at that 1 time, it never will again - they are moving same speed around the same loop.

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. If you want people to help you, you have to enable them to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a problem when the cycle is made at the head node, i.e. when all the list's nodes are in the cycle. In that case the `if` condition will be true when `slow` and `fast` are back at the head node. Consequently, the `while` condition will immediately be false, and then `pre.next` will be an invalid reference, as `pre` never changed from its initial `null` value.

The pragmatic way to solve this, is to create a dummy node that is prefixed to the head node, and start the process from that dummy node. Now you can be sure that the dummy node is *not* part of the cycle, and thus this boundary case will not occur.

Alternatively you could set `pre` also in the outer loop, so that it follows behind `slow`. That will give you a good "initial" value for `pre` for when the inner `while` loop starts.

So add one more line to your code:

```java
public static void removeLoop(Node head){       
    Node slow=head;
    Node fast=head;
    Node node=head;
    Node pre=null;
    while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
        pre=slow; // <--- add this!
        slow=slow.next;
        fast=fast.next.next;
        if(slow==fast){
            while(node!=slow){
                pre=slow;
                node=node.next;
                slow=slow.next;
            }
            pre.next=null;
        }
    }
}
```